Struct Drag Position Variable Read as 0
I have a TouchModelerContentView view which is a ScrollView with two TableView views.
The TableView view has a DragGesture which allows for moving the view around the ScrollView.
I want to draw a line between the two TableView views, and for that I need to access the offset stored in the Table struct, but when I try to access it from TouchModelerContentView, it returns the offset as (0, 0) despite me having dragged the tables on the screen.
TouchModelerContentView
ScrollView {
    ZStack {
        ForEach($tables) { $table in
            TableView(table: $table)
        }
        
        ForEach(tables) { table in
            ForEach(table.relations) { relation in
                Path { path in
                    path.move(to: CGPoint(x: relation.source.offset.width, y: relation.source.offset.height))
                    path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: relation.target.offset.width, y: relation.target.offset.height))
                    
                    print("\(relation.source.name) \(relation.source.offset) -> \(relation.target.name) \(relation.target.offset)") // Prints "Table2 (0.0, 0.0) -> Table1 (0.0, 0.0)" 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Table struct
struct Table: Identifiable {
    struct Relation: Identifiable {
        let id = UUID()
        let source: Table
        let target: Table
    }
    
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var relations = [Relation]()
    var startingOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var currentOffset: CGSize = .zero
    var offset: CGSize {
        CGSize(width: startingOffset.width + currentOffset.width, height: startingOffset.height + currentOffset.height)
    }
}

TableView View (where offset is being set)
struct TableView: View {
    @Binding var table: Table
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ...
        }
        .offset(table.offset)
        .gesture(
            DragGesture()
                .onChanged { gesture in
                    table.currentOffset = gesture.translation
                }
                .onEnded{ gesture in
                    table.startingOffset.width += table.currentOffset.width
                    table.startingOffset.height += table.currentOffset.height
                    table.currentOffset = .zero
                }
        )
    }
}

TableView must be setting the offsets correctly because I can drag the tables in my simulator and see their position change, however, when I try to retrieve the offset inside TouchModelerContentView, I get a (0, 0) position. Why isn't the correct offset being retrieved?
